# How can I get two calculators going?

Tags: mac, applications, macos

Is there anyway I can have two instances of native Calculator app running simultaneously.

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd want two instances of Calculator. I set Calculator to RPN mode, this gives you a stack that can store intermediate results.

Comment: The calculator app in Windows 10 will open as many instances as you like..

Comment: @Hobbes I'm wondering why you would think someone wouldn't want to be able to run two instances of Calculator... maybe they want to do two different calculations at the same time (for some reason) without writing down their intermediate answers.

Comment: In RPN mode your intermediate results remain visible if you want. No need to have a second window open. https://igor.io/2013/12/02/stack-machines-rpn.html

Comment: Also, I was asking for a use case because that would enable a better recommendation.

Comment: Working on two calculations simultaneously seems like an abundantly obvious use case. This is the same use case for anybody ever wanting two instances of the same application open.

Comment: The best solution is really to dual boot Windows. Then you can just press the calculator button on your keyboard to open up a copy of the app. It's so easy.

Comment: Before upgrading from Mojave to Catalina, I had two calculators on my dashboard (I don't remember how I did it, but it was very useful). It was just about the only thing I ever did with the dashboard. Then the folks at Apple did away with the dashboard entirely.

Answer (score 76):

The quickest, simplest and arguably most correct way of doing this is using the `open` command in Terminal.

In a new window, run the command

```
open -na Calculator
```

This will open a new (`-n`) instance of the application (`-a`) Calculator.

If you want to have this handy at the click of a button, you can type the following commands into the Terminal, and it will create a shortcut named `calc` or `calc.command` on your desktop that will always open a new instance of Calculator

```
cd ~/Desktop
echo open -na Calculator > calc.command
chmod +x calc.command
exit
```

Mind that you don't already have a file named `calc.command` on your desktop, or it'll be deleted!

Comment: How does `open` work ? It checks for whatever is in the Applications folder ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon see the man page [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html). I don't see it saying explicitly anywhere, but it looks like it's either checking `/Applications` or using `LaunchServices` to find it.

Comment: @GabrielRomon There is a metadata database that tracks stuff like applications; it includes applications found in `/Applications` and sub-directories, `~/Applications` and sub-directories, and even places like `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

Comment: A way that I find helps me "understand" the "open" command is to consider it a direct synonym for the "start" command under Windows.  Many many many years ago, that was described to me as "Do whatever is the appropriate thing to make sense of the opened (started) object."  So in the case of an app, it'll open it, in the case of a document it'll open it in the associated application, in the case of a url it'll open it in a new browser tab, etc.

Comment: @dgnuff Another easy way of looking at it is that `open` is roughly equivalent to a double-click.

Comment: Just pointing out how absurd the Mac is for forcing someone to open a terminal and type cryptic text in to just spawn another instance of the most basic tool a computer has.

Answer (score 20):

The `open -na Calculator` answer is good.  When I needed to do this before, I wrapped it in an Applescript:

```applescript
 do shell script "open -n " & quoted form of the POSIX path of the (path to the frontmost application as Unicode text)
```

This detects which application is currently in the foreground and starts a new instance using the `open -na` method.

Save this script in the Applescript Editor as something like "Run another instance" and put it in your `/Users/${USER}/Library/Scripts` directory.  You will then find it under the User Scripts Menu ([which you may need to enable](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/UsetheSystem-WideScriptMenu.html)):

[image]

Simply bring the calculator to the foreground, then select this menu item and you'll get another calculator instance.

Comment: In my opinion, this is by far the best answer, as it is the most general. I.E. do this one thing once, and now you can run multiple instances of any app, not just the Calculator.

Answer (score 9):

You can run as many as you like and even without duplicates  of the application.

Double click the application to open one instance, e.g.

```
/Applications/Calculator.app
```

Then double click the executable to open a second instance
 (you will have to ctrl+click or right-click the application and select "Show Package Contents" to navigate to the executable):

```
/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
```

In this second instance a Terminal window will open to run the executable.  Don't terminate it, or you will terminate the second instance of Calculator running.

Double clicking the executable lets you open as many instances of Calculator as you like (meaning I don't know the upper limit).

Comment: You can also run "/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator" &              
from terminal as many times as you want and then close the terminal window.

Comment: Yes, that avoids navigating to the executable in Finder, but I still need the window open, or all instances will be terminated.

Comment: Right you are! It seems my recollection was a bit off.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can, if you have an administrator account. Select Calculator.app in Applications, then right-click (control-click) and execute the `Duplicate` command. This will make a copy of the Calculator app which you can then use freely.

[image]

Comment: This will not make an application run twice but will create a copy of the application and then run the copy

Comment: @Matteo - Yes, correct, but what's the problem here? The OP requested "How can I get two calculators going?" and it does just that.

Comment: It works but it’s a waste of space. To execute an application twice you don’t need the same information on the disk twice.

Comment: @Matteo - I still don't see how your comment adds to my post. You're merely stating facts gleaned from other answers. Nothing is wrong with my answer in the least. There may be more elegant ways of running Calculator multiple times, but it works. In any case, 11.7MB of disk space for 2 copies of Calculator is minimal compared with the size of, say, Pages (508MB), Keynote (728MB), Excel (1.75GB!), or even Final Cut Pro (3.76GB.)

Comment: There are potentially other problems, like when the original gets updated. @Matteo What about a symlink? This would save space and be automatically updated.

Comment: @IconDaemon it's a bad solution. the question is "run the same app" twice and this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Open your terminal and run:

```
open -n /Applications/Calculator.app
```

or

```
open -na Calculator
```

No need for app copying or anything like that!

From the help options for `open`:

```
-n, --new         Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.
-a                Opens with the specified application.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the calculator app to a different folder or desktop. Now change the name to something different like Calc ( very original I know). You can now run both.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to change sharing permissions on the Calculator.app file and make a copy using the Duplicate option, then this way should work for you.

- Open the Shortcuts app that comes with macOS.
- Create a new shortcut with the plus sign.
- In the *'Search for apps and actions'* field at top right type the word "run"
- Now drag the '**Run Shell Script**' option from the right pane into the main pane for your action. (Note: You may be prompted to allow running scripts).
- Replace the default `echo "Hello World"` script text with:
  `open -n /System/Applications/Calculator.app`.
- Rename your shortcut from "Run Shell Script" to something more meaningful (remembering to press <kbd>return</kbd>) and then close the window.
- Go back to the main Shortcuts window and drag your newly created shortcut from the "**All Shortcuts**" main pane to the "**Menu Bar**" folder in the right pane.
- You should now be able to access the shortcut in your top menu bar and create multiple instances with it.