# Activity Monitor - How to view multiple panels at the same time

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

I'm currently trying to view multiple metrics at the same time using Activity Monitor app (yes I have tried `top`, `htop`, etc but I was wondering if this is possible with Activity Monitor). 
Fx. looking at the CPU and Memory panels without having to switch between them.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Some graphics of CPU can be seen by Windows -> CPU history alongside Memory.

Comment: That's the same principle as the following post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325420/how-can-i-get-two-calculators-going/325435#325435 "View > Columns" should let you enable what you need, no matter which tab you are under.

Comment: iSts menus can show multiple things - e.g. overal CPU, memory, network - but is a menu app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose your own set of columns to be displayed on any particular tab by right-clicking on the column headers (or View → Columns) and checking columns to be displayed. For example, this lets you show the Memory column while on the GPU tab.

If you really want to display two different tabs using two windows, you can launch a second instance of Activity Monitor with `open -na "Activity Monitor"`.