# How can i open multiple instance of electron application in MAC OS?

Tags: macos, mac, javascript

i have an electron node application which i can open multiple instances in windows but not in MAC OS , how can i achieve the same functionality in mac also ?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325420/how-can-i-get-two-calculators-going

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Windows, MacOS normally opens only one instance of an app, regardless of the number of documents or windows currently running within it.

It is possible to launch additional instances using `open -n /path/to/myApp.app`

Comment: not like that, actually i want to run my application from visual studio only, the build is not there for the application, in local i want to test my code

Comment: @satishVudata Then please add that information to your question, along with any other relevant details of exactly what you want.